# Pass large JSONObject when opening a new page

Tags: jquery, json, web, store

I am building a website and communicate with a backend web-service, so far I haven't use any database connection yet, so it's pure html, Javascript and Css.

Right now, I retrieved a large JSONObject from web-service api, and I need to pass this JSONObject when opening a new page, such as calling window.location(newpage). Normally saving data in Cookie is my option, but just realized there is size limitation with Cookie.

I am web greener, and wondering if there is good suggestion how I should solve this problem? Should I build an database to store the data?

By the way, my website is under the Tomcat.

**Update**
This website is built with HTML4 not HTML5.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or any other JavaScript library?

Comment: Hi, DevlshOne, Yes, I am using jQuery. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll write something in the answer box for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using jQuery's `data` method. For instance, if *jData* is your previously retrieved JSON data, you can do this:

**On the original page**

```
$(function() {
// your routine to retrieve the jSON data
$('#temp').data('myJSON', jData);
// ...
window.location(newpage);
}
```

****On the new page****

```
$(function() {
jData = $('#temp').data('myJSON');
// process the JSON data
}
```

jQuery will store the data in memory so you do not need to worry about cookie length limitations or creating an inline or external db.

Comment: Hi, DevlshOne, this is a solution, but this is actually saving data within a html element, right? I think user can see this data from browser inspector.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/data/

This does not place any text or values within the DOM, it only attaches the data to an element or object at the 'internal memory' level.